# How the WMS services can be secured such that it can be accessed by Esri and non-Esri clients

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, authentication

I couldn't figure out if there is a method to secure WMS services such that it can be accessed by Esri and non-Esri clients.
Is there a code can I write it some where?

Answer (score 3):

To secure WMS services on ArcGIS server, you can use token-based authentication.

**ArcGIS Server managed token-based authentication**

Although not recommended, a WMS service can still be secured using ArcGIS Server managed token-based authentication by using this type of authentication on its parent map or image service. To make raw requests to WMS services protected by a token, you can get a valid token from the token service and append the token string as an extra parameter to the requests you send out. In other words, requests to a token-secured WMS service must use the following format:

`http://<WMS_service_url>?<standard WMS parameters>&token=<valid_tokenString>`

Most third-party desktop WMS clients will not be able to connect to WMS services secured in this way, but this technique can be used with WMS clients built with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

**Reference:**
http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/linux/wms-services.htm#GUID-BB6D9497-6981-407F-BF9F-4ED3BB615024

Answer (score 0):

OGC WMS and WMTS services secured with web-tier authentication, such as Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA), a public key infrastructure (PKI), Basic, or Digest access authentication, are supported. OGC WMS and WMTS services secured with token-based authentication are not supported. Configure support for OGC services secured with web-tier authentication by adding the server hosting the services to your organization’s list of trusted servers. The server must support CORS; otherwise, layers hosted on the server will not function as expected in ArcGIS Online. If you will access the secure OGC service with Internet Explorer, you may need to add the domain of your organization’s trusted servers to your browser’s trusted sites list.

https://doc.arcgis.com/it/arcgis-online/reference/ogc.htm

so it depends how you've configured the web adapter.

if you have configurated with token-based authentication (gis-tier) user can generate token from rest page with user/password and use it in additional/custom parameters
for example in arcmap you can use 'custom parameters'.

[image]